# Rails 5 instance level helpers method in controller not recognizing helpers. method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, helper

I'm trying to follow the "New way to call helper methods in Rails 5" mentioned [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/06/26/rails-add-helpers-method-to-ease-usage-of-helper-modules-in-controllers.html), originally PR [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24866).

I can get the "old approach" to work with the following:

```
# app/models/order.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CustomersHelper
  # some code...

  def name_make_uppercase
    self.first_name = uppercase(first_name)
    self.last_name = uppercase(last_name)
  end
end

# app/helperss/customers_helper.rb
module CustomersHelper
  def uppercase(input)
    return unless input
    input[0] = input[0].to_s.capitalize
    input
  end
end
```

However, with the new approach I believe I should be able to remove the "include CustomersHelper" and add "helpers." to my uppercase functions in the controller e.g.

```
# app/models/order.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # include CustomersHelper
  # some code...

  def name_make_uppercase
    self.first_name = helpers.uppercase(first_name)
    self.last_name = helpers.uppercase(last_name)
  end
end
```

However, now my spec's are getting the following error:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `helpers' for #Customer:0x00000004d50be8>

I'm curious what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `helpers` method is only available in **controllers**, you are trying to use it in a **model**. Models don't (and shouldn't) have knowledge about their views/controllers/helpers.

It looks like what you need is either a regular module (i.e. not a Rails helper) or perhaps a decorator (e.g. [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)) In any case the `helpers` method won't help you here.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to keep your helper methods restricted to view templates and not mix view helpers into rails model classes.

You can simply use `capitalize` (ruby standard library method for `String` class) to your instance attributes from your model instance method as well.

```
# app/models/order.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

  def name_make_uppercase
    self.first_name = first_name.capitalize
    self.last_name = last_name.capitalize
  end

end
```

and use it:

```
c = Customer.new(first_name: 'bruce', last_name: 'wayne')
c.name_make_upcase
c.first_name #=> 'Bruce'
c.last_name #=> 'Wayne'
```